# Ending a sentence in ぞと

Tags: usage, particles, register

One of the people I follow on twitter sometimes ends his sentences in ぞと. Is this just a more polite form of ぞ？

Here's an example:

> ブログUPしましたぞと♪(´ε｀ )

Answer (score 6):

This `ぞと` should be broken down into two particles:

- `...ぞ`: reinforces and reminds one's decision or will to oneself

  - ex. さあ、やるぞ。Here I go.
- `...と`: light declaration

  - ex. いつか行こうっと。I'll visit there one day.

So your example roughly means, "There, I've posted a new blog article." And no, it doesn't add any politeness to the sentence.

The same `と` is discussed in [this board](https://web.archive.org/web/20110602195339/http://nihongo-online.jp/bbs/discuss.cgi?id=20&mode=part&page=0&num=2401&sort=1&back=tree) (Japanese), which cites 明鏡国語辞典 {めいきょうこくごじてん} (Meikyo Japanese Dictionary):

> （「・・・っと」の形で）軽く言い放つのに使う。 (In the form of ...っと) used to declare something lightly.

The preceding sentence is usually in volitional form, like  `もう寝ようっと`. Or, as in the case of ...ぞ, expresses volition in some other way.

Note: depending on the context, there are cases that ぞと should be parsed as 「...ぞ」と, as explained in istrasci's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would split the example sentence into two parts:

> ブログUPしましたぞ / と

Unfortunately, I cannot explain how the と affects the other part well, but as far as I can say as a Japanese, the と is a kind of like an interjection and its effect is vanishingly small, at least not making the sentence more polite.

FYI, [Reno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_of_the_Final_Fantasy_VII_series#Reno), a Final Fantasy 7 character, often ends his words with `〜ぞ、と。` or `〜だぞ、と。` the same way as the example. The person may perhaps just imitate this habit.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of (without any context provided) is that this would be used when quoting what someone else said.  Like:

> 彼は心斎橋へ行くぞと言った　【He said "Let's go to Shinsaibashi"】　→　Making known that he said something, and what it was.
>
> みんなでどうしたらいいかについて彼は意見を言った。心斎橋へ行くぞと　【He gave his opinion about what we should all do together.  "Let's all go to Shinsaibashi!"】　→　The fact that he said something was previously known.  Now it's being made known what he said.